# Subspaces and Dimensions Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been asked to show that given two subspaces of $M_{22}$  M and N  that $ \dim(M) + \dim(N) = \dim(M + N) + \dim(M \cap N)$ holds. Here is my solution that is 'incorrect' but I feel like every step is concrete so my question is this, is this a valid approach?

Now consider the sub-spaces M and N defined by:

$M =\{\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ -b & c\end{bmatrix}: a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\} $

$\{\quad N=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}:a+3d = 0 \land b-2c =0  \in \mathbb{R}\} $

We now incorporate the conditions of N into the matrix
$N = \ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ \frac{1}{2}b & -\frac{1}{3}a\end{bmatrix}$

Now looking at the intersection of M and N we have:
$M \cap N  = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Now looking at the addition of M and N we have:

$M + N  = \begin{bmatrix} 2a & 2b \\ -\frac{1}{2}b & c-\frac{1}{3}a\end{bmatrix}$

Looking at the spans we have:

\begin{align*}
 & \operatorname{Span}(M) = \Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} , \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Big\} \\
 \\
 & \operatorname{Span}(N) = \Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix}\Big\} \\
 \\
 & \operatorname{Span}(M+N)  \Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -\frac{1}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\Big\} \\
 \\
 & \operatorname{Span}(M \cap N)  \Big\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\Big\}
\end{align*}

By inspection we can see that the matrices in each span are linearly independent of  one another, that is no members are linear combinations of the others.

Now as each of these spans are linearly independent they form a basis for each respective subspaces, thus the cardinality of these spans gives us the dimensions of the subspaces. \vspace{0.2cm}

We can now see that $\dim(M) + \dim(N) = \dim(M + N) + \dim(M \cap N)$ as required.

Comment: This formula is very general, and has nothing to do with matrices. If you know about exact sequences, we can say it is obvious considering a convenient exact sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your  input, unfortunately i don't know anything about exact sequences :( was just wonder if my working  shows that given the vector space of 2x2 matrices that these sub spaces do indeed satisfy this general formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is *almost* correct for this specific example, but your calculation on $M+N$ has flaws: we can't assume that the variables $a, b$ are the same, i.e.
$$M+N=\{\pmatrix{a_1+a_2&b_1+b_2\\-b_1+\frac12b_2&c-\frac13 a_2}\}$$
If you prove that all such matrices are in the span you gave, it will finish the proof.

Otherwise note that it's a general statement that holds for every subspaces $M, N$ of any vector space $V$.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this :)

Answer (score 1):

*Another (general) approach*:

Consider the linear map:
\begin{align}
f:M\times N&\longrightarrow M+N, \\
(m,n)&\longmapsto m+n.
\end{align}
By definition, this map is surjective. Show that $\ker f$ is isomorphic to $M\cap N$, and apply the *rank-nullity formula*.

Comment: Maybe it's even more straightforward with $(m, n) \mapsto m-n$.

Comment: @Berci: I know, but I thought it might be harder to understand for beginners.

Comment: Ok, then I realized, $m-n$ straightforwardly gives the identity for the kernel, but we have to switch for the identity for the image. While the other map $m+n$ gives the image straightforwardly.. So, indeed it doesn't matter